# Workshop- How to elegantly show data with an icon in object table based on conditional values

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have an object table in Workshop and I have a column which I want to display yes values with a tick mark and no with a "X". Just another visual representation.
Now in ontology we have conditional formatting, but that just colors the cell and the data is the same. I just want a tick in that place.

Is there anyway to achieve this? Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this with a "derived property" function and an emoji. Structurally this looks like building a `FunctionMap` return type that maps each object to the corresponding new value. To do this efficiently (especially if need do make some other aggregation or Ontology API call *for each element* then you should write a little helper function:

```
        @Function()
        public async flagBooleanWithIcon(objects: ObjectSet<MyObjectType>): Promise<FunctionsMap<LifecycleStage,string>> {
            const map = new FunctionsMap<MyObjectType,string>()
            const objectsList = objects.all();
            await Promise.all(
                ObjectList.map(o => this.setIconInResult(map, o))
            );
            
            return map;
        }
    
    private async setIconInResult(result: FunctionsMap<MyObjectType,string>, object: MyObjectType) {
            result.set(object, ❌)
         
            if (object.booleanProperty ?? false) {
                 result.set(stage, '')
            }
        }
```

Then in your Workshop Object Table, follow the instructions for a [function-backed column](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/widgets-object-table/#function-backed-columns).